# Passing data to Alert eventListener

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

Probably a standard/old question but so far I haven't been able to find any info.

I need to add a "confirm delete" Alert to an existing function (`selectNode`) below. In order to handle the Alert callback, I need to store a reference to the `node` param so I can operate on it in the callback. I know I can make a `var` to store it in but I am wondering if there is a way I can pack it in either a custom event that the `Alert` panel can use, or if there is some sort of `data` property I can assign on the Alert.

```
    private function selectNode(node:Node):void{

    if(editor.currentTool == "deleteTool"){

         Alert.show("Delete selected node?",
                "Delete Node:", Alert.OK | Alert.CANCEL, null, nodeDeleteConfirm, 
                 null, Alert.CANCEL);

                // moving this to the callback
                unmarkNodes();
                node.mark();
                removeNode(node);
            }  else {
                unmarkNodes();
                node.mark();
            }

        }


        private function nodeDeleteConfirm(evt:CloseEvent):void
        {
            if(evt.detail == Alert.OK){

             } 
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define inner function to access the parameter of outer function:

```
private function selectNode(node:Node):void{

    if(editor.currentTool == "deleteTool"){

        Alert.show("Delete selected node?",
            "Delete Node:", Alert.OK | Alert.CANCEL, null, nodeDeleteConfirm, 
             null, Alert.CANCEL);
        //code moved from here.

        }  else {
            unmarkNodes();
            node.mark();
        }
    function nodeDeleteConfirm(evt:CloseEvent):void
    {
        if(evt.detail == Alert.OK){
            // moving this to the callback
            unmarkNodes();
            node.mark();
            removeNode(node);
        } 
    }

}
```